# Customize Jenkins pipeline stage view

Tags: jenkins, plugins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

How can i add the little blue tags to stage view in a Jenkins Pipeline?

[image]

Comment: Did you find out? i'm wondering the same question...

Comment: @MarcKellerman Never found out :( still hoping someone will answer this

Comment: any news about this? need to use that feature :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was searching for this as well and found the following after reading Hatim's answer:

The line that was supposed to show the node label is commented out:
[source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/blob/master/ui/src/main/js/view/templates/pipeline-staged.hbs#L107)

The referenced issue [JENKINS-33290](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33290) is `Resolved` with the last comment:

> Resolved by removing the functionality, since a correct implementation imposes unacceptable complexity and overhead.

So I'm afraid it's not coming back soon and all those screenshots online are outdated.

Answer (score -1):

Is the name or label of the node used.

Please refer to this
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/

```
node: Allocate node
Allocates an executor on a node (typically a slave) and runs further code in the context of a workspace on that slave.
label
Computer name, label name, or any other label expression like linux && 64bit to restrict where this step builds. May be left blank, in which case any available executor is taken.
```

In this case, the stage is executed in the master, if you configure your jenkins pipeline to be executed in differents plateforms (master-slaves), then you will be able to see the label of your slaves environement.